# Reading all objects from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, multidimensional-array

I want to read all objects from multidimensional array which looks like this:

```
const useMap = ref([
  // ====================== ROW 1 ======================
  [
    {
      x: 1,
      y: 1,
      currentPosition: false,
      color: "white",
      isWinning: false,
    },
    {
      x: 16,
      y: 1,
      currentPosition: false,
      color: "white",
      isWinning: false,
    },
  ],
  // ====================== ROW 2 ======================
  [
    {
      x: 1,
      y: 2,
      currentPosition: false,
      color: "white",
      isWinning: false,
    },
    {
      x: 16,
      y: 2,
      currentPosition: false,
      color: "white",
      isWinning: false,
    },

...
```

Already Im reading values by single rows like this:

```
      <div v-for="tile in map[0]" :key:="tile" :tile="tile">
        <div class="tile">{{ tile.y }} | {{ tile.x }}</div>
      </div>
      <div v-for="tile in map[1]" :key:="tile" :tile="tile">
        <div class="tile">{{ tile.y }} | {{ tile.x }}</div>
      </div>

...
```

Is there any option to read all rows once and not by single rows?

Comment: This should be easy to solve. You need a nested loop:
`<div v-for="map in useMap">
  <div v-for="tile in map" :key:="tile" :tile="tile">
    <div class="tile">{{ tile.y }} | {{ tile.x }}</div>
  </div>
</div>`

haven't write it as answer to avoid downvotes

Comment: @ericmp haha, don't feel scared. You could also probably use a flatMap: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Comment: @kissu yeah but sometimes answer but get downvote cuz the question is not well-asked and/or is a duplicate, so in this case can happen i think

Comment: @DavidBr8 Just an informational note: JS does not have multidimensional arrays  (unlike some languages like C). JS does permit nested arrays, however (which look and behave a bit like multidimensional arrays).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this requirement by converting the multi dimensional array into a single dimensional array using [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method and then iterate the values using `v-for` in the template.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const { ref, reactive, readonly, computed } = Vue;

const App = {
  setup () {
    const useMap = ref([
      [
        {
          x: 1,
          y: 1,
          currentPosition: false,
          color: "white",
          isWinning: false,
        },
        {
          x: 16,
          y: 1,
          currentPosition: false,
          color: "white",
          isWinning: false,
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          x: 1,
          y: 2,
          currentPosition: false,
          color: "white",
          isWinning: false,
        },
        {
          x: 16,
          y: 2,
          currentPosition: false,
          color: "white",
          isWinning: false,
        }
      ]
    ])

    const tiles = computed(() => useMap.value.flat());

    return { tiles }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="tile in tiles" :key:="tile" :tile="tile">
    <div class="tile">{{ tile.y }} | {{ tile.x }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested arrays can be flattened with `flat`, and a computed is used to transform data to required shape before it's used:

```
const tiles = computed(() => useMap.value.flat());
```

Then it's used like intended:

```
  <div v-for="tile in tiles" :key:="tile" :tile="tile">
```